# Betton are not disappear when removing atomFamily recoil.js

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

Why when user click "remove button" in ListItem component, the item text are disappear but the button itself are still there, if possible how to get rid of that "remove button" too?

P.S The atom family item are got removed but the ui are not get updated ("remove button" are still there), is that a normal things?

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { atom, useRecoilState, useResetRecoilState, useRecoilCallback, atomFamily, useRecoilValue, useSetRecoilState } from "recoil";
import "./styles.css";



const idsState = atom({ 
    key: "circleColor", 
    default: [],
});


const noteState = atomFamily({
    key: "noteState",
    default: []
})




const ListItem = ({ id }) => {

    const [note, setNote] = useRecoilState(noteState(id));

    const handleRemoveNote = useResetRecoilState(noteState(id));


    return (
        <div key={note.id} className="list-item">
            <p>{note.text}</p>
            <button onClick={handleRemoveNote}>Remove</button>
        </div>
    )
}


const App = () => { 
    const ids = useRecoilValue(idsState);
    const nextId = ids.length;

    const addNote = useRecoilCallback(({set}) => (newNote) => {
        set(idsState, [...ids, nextId])
        set(noteState(nextId), newNote);
    })

    const [text, setText] = useState("");


    const handleAddNote = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const id = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
    
        const newNote = {
            text,
            id,
            subNote: [
                {
                    label: "zero",
                    value: "0"
                },
                {
                   label: "one",
                   value: "1"
                },
                {
                   label: "two",
                   value: "two"
                }
            ]
        };
    
        addNote(newNote);
    }


    return ( 
        <div> 
            <form className="form-container" onSubmit={handleAddNote}>
                <input onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} />
                <button>Add</button>
            </form>
            <div>
                {ids.map(id => (
                    <ListItem id={id} />
                ))} 
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: You're missing the `key` attribute in `ids.map`. use `<ListItem id={id} key={id} />`

Comment: But i already gave listItem a key "key={note.id}"

Comment: You have it in the wrong location, it's supposed to be in the map callback, not the component you're mapping to. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Thanks for documentation btw, but still the "remove button", are not disappearing when get clicked